# Pass data from child component to parent component in Angular @ViewChild Expected 2 arguments

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, viewchild, angular-event-emitter

In here i am trying to pass data using `@Output & EventEmitter` and `@ViewChild & AfterViewInit` from child to parent.

This is my parent component .html file.

```
<app-child (filterEvent)=" getValuesFromFilters($event)" [name]="name"></app-child>
```

This is my parent component .ts file

```
name = 'View';
@ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;
getValuesFromFilters($event) {
  this.criteria = $event;
  console.log(this.criteria);
  this.apply();
}
```

This is my ChildComponent .html file

```
<button (click)="applyValues()" mat-raised-button>
  Apply
</button>
```

This my ChildComponent .ts file

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() filterEvent = new EventEmitter < any > ();
  @Input() name: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
  applyValues() {
    this.filterEvent.emit(this.filterValues);
    console.log(this.filterValues);
  }
}
```

In here if i click the apply button in child component, values coming from child to parent as i am emitting an event. But i want to get the values from child to parent component on the first page load of the parent. Therefore i am trying to use `@ViewChild` in parent component. But it gives this error.

TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.  core.d.ts(8070, 47): An argument for 'opts' was not provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<app-child #Child (filterEvent)=" getValuesFromFilters($event)" [name]="name"></app-child>
```

```
@ViewChild("Child", { static: true }) child: ChildComponent;
```

Comment: In here i am trying to get values from child to parent in `ngAfterViewInit() { this.criteria = this.child.filterValues; console.log(this.criteria);}` But parent loads before child

Comment: first it prints values in `ngAfterViewInit()` and after that child component values process.Therefore  `this.criteria` coming as null. I want to get values to the parent component after child component values process